# how to read data from notepad with tab separation as wells as semicolon

Tags: r, text, import

I have the following data in notepad:

first few rows of `notepad.txt`:

```
    ;sales_organization;campaign_type;campaign_name;brand;sub_brand;ppg;scan_upc;year;sundayendwk;trade_spend;paid_media_spend;advertising_agency_fees;media_production;talent_residuals;accrued_deferred_advertising;advertising_prior_year;coupon_insertion_and_placemen;pr_publicity;consumer_coupon_redemption;consumer_coupon_handling;coupon_prior_year;consumer_incentives_premiums;sme_agency_fees_third_party_promoters;website_maintenanc;sponsorship_event_fees;other_dmes_prior_year;design_services;packaging_prepress_comps;sample_programs;point_of_sale_materials;marketing_samples_cust_svc;marketing_research;sales_materials;printing_charges_miscellaneous_smes;commercial_data_fees;total_other_dme_spend;pm_comp_avg_grp;trade_dme_comp;comp_distribution;comp_revenue;comp_avg_price_per_unit;comp_avg_base_price;unit_sales;dollar_sales;price_per_unit;average_weekly_acv_distribution;base_dollar_sales;incremental_dollars;dollars_per_mm_acv;weighted_average_base_price_per_unit;total_points_of_distribution;visualization_value
1    ;US01         ;ZC05      ;Z019      ;HER        ;HER060   ;HER060210;000003400013335999;2019         ;20190721     ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0            ;0           ;0          ;0          ;0             ;0.01          ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0          ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0.01         ;95.497 ;0           ;0        ;0          ;0         ;0          ;1           ;5           ;5           ;0           ;5           ;0           ;0.05       ;0           ;0.03        ;US WALMART  
2    ;US01         ;ZC05      ;Z019      ;HER        ;HER060   ;HER060258;000003400013344999;2019         ;20190224     ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0            ;0           ;0          ;0          ;0             ;0.013         ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0          ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0.013        ;79.631 ;0           ;0        ;0          ;0         ;0          ;18          ;444.45      ;5           ;0           ;444.45      ;0           ;0.15       ;0           ;0.01        ;US WALMART  
3    ;US01         ;ZC05      ;Z019      ;REE        ;REE055   ;REE055238;000003400041723999;2019         ;20190310     ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0            ;0           ;0          ;0          ;0             ;0.015         ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0          ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0.015        ;75.074 ;0           ;0        ;0          ;0         ;0          ;2           ;1           ;0.5         ;0           ;1           ;0           ;0.01       ;0           ;0.08        ;US WALMART  
4    ;US01         ;ZC05      ;Z019      ;REE        ;REE055   ;REE055238;000003400041723999;2019         ;20190324     ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0            ;0           ;0          ;0          ;0             ;0.015         ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0          ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0.015        ;39.554 ;0           ;0        ;0          ;0         ;0          ;5           ;3.6         ;1.1         ;0           ;3.6         ;0           ;0.01       ;0           ;0.12        ;US WALMART  
5    ;US01         ;ZC05      ;Z019      ;REE        ;REE055   ;REE055238;000003400041723999;2019         ;20190331     ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0            ;0           ;0          ;0          ;0             ;0.015         ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0          ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0.015        ;65.396 ;0           ;0        ;0          ;0         ;0          ;2           ;1           ;1           ;0           ;1           ;0           ;0.01       ;0           ;0.09        ;US WALMART  
6    ;US01         ;ZC05      ;Z019      ;REE        ;REE055   ;REE055238;000003400041723999;2019         ;20190414     ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0            ;0           ;0          ;0          ;0             ;0.015         ;0             ;0            ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0          ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0             ;0.015        ;106.73 ;0           ;0        ;0          ;0         ;0          ;1           ;0.5         ;0.5         ;0           ;0.5         ;0           ;0.01       ;0           ;0.03        ;US WALMART
```

I tried doing the following:

```
notepad_06042021<-read.delim("notepad.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ";")
```

But i am not getting the desired data frame structure. Need help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
notepad_06042021<-read.delim("notepad.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";") %>%
mutate_all(~gsub("^\t|\t$", "", .))
```

This will read your table with the semicolon as separator and then remove the tabs later on.